# Grandchildren of an element (XPath)

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm searching for a XPath expresssion, which gives me all grandchildren of an element.

Is this correct: child/child/* ?

Comment: Good question (+1)! See the correct answer. Hint: it is not the currently selected one... :)

Comment: is text node of a child considered grandchild?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*/*` gives all grandchildren see http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/xpath.xtp

Answer (score 4):

> Is this correct: child/child/* ?

No,

`child`

selects all children elements of the current node, whose name is `child`.

`child/child`

selects all elements named `child` that ara children of any element named `child` that is a child of the current node. **So, the above expression selects all grandchildren of the current node, that are named `child` and whose parents are also named `child`.** This is closest to "grandchildren of an element".

The XPath expression you are asking about:

`child/child/*`

selects all elements (regardless of name) that are children of elements named `child` that are children of elements named `child` that are children of the current node. These are some of the current node's grand-grand-children (children of the grandchildren).

**To answer completely the question, the following expression selects all grandchildren of the current node**:

`*/node()`

These are all nodes that are children of all elements that are children of the current node.

**Note the following**:

1. Only elements and the document node can have children.
2. Any node (with the exception of the document node), not only an element node, can be and usually is a child of some other node. Therefore, there can be grandchildren that are not elements -- such as text nodes, comment nodes and processing-instruction nodes. Attributes and namespace nodes are technically not children.